# Evolution - Categories Task Filter filters only on the first category

Tags: 17.04, evolution

Running Evolution 3.22.6 on Ubuntu Gnome on Wayland.

My tasks are stored in a CalDAV calendar and I attach multiple categories to each task.

The tasks view lets me filter the tasks based on categories. Except that for some categories, it will not filter the task if that is the second category. For some other categories, it correctly filters the tasks.

The behaviour is the same even if I Search for a particular category. For some categories, it will select the tasks correctly. For some others, it will not.

To my mind, that is not correct. EVERYTIME, it should look at ALL categories attached to the task to see if it fits the bill.

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Comment: Strange issue, I'm also using Evolution 3.22.6, and I'm syncing my tasks with Nextcloud, I my filter are working all the time even if I add two or more categories.

Comment: @olivierb2 Let me update. It is erratic. For some categories, it shows the tasks when the list is  filtered for that category and even if it is not the first category. For some others, it does not. FWIW, I am using Gnome on Wayland

Comment: sorry, I guess you should open a bug report for those kind of issue, not sure there is anything to do manually.

Comment: @olivierb2 Where do I open a bug report? I thought discussing it here would suffice

Comment: @olivierb2 it requires no space between categories. So, if it's cat1,cat2 it'll filter properly. But if it's cat1, cat2 it'll ignore cat2 while filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Gnome Evolution requires that there is no space between categories. So, the categories must be entered as `Category1,Category2,Category with space 3,Cat4` Note that there is no space after the ,. Then it will filter correctly. HTH